# How to write value1 || value2 in shell?

Tags: shell

I would make a simple script in shell and put a default value in case the user enters nothing. Here is my script:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "checkpoint commit"
git push
```

I would make something like

```
git add -A
git commit -m ($1 || "checkpoint commit")
git push
```

Comment: Look up "parameter expansion" in your shell's documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

`git commit -m "${1:-checkpoint commit}"`

If `$1` is set, `${1:-checkpoint commit}` will expand to the value of `$1`.

If `$1` is not set, it will expand to whatever is after the :- (ie "checkpoint commit" in this example).